# Display a div containing a particular String

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a drop-down list with 3 options. These options are being echoed inside multiple div's. The heading of each of these div is either of these 3 options. How can I only display the div's containing that particular drop-down value.

```
<select id="level">
    <option value="00" selected><b>Default</b></option>
    <option value="Primaire">Primary</option>
    <option value="Secondaire">Secondary</option>
    <option value="Primaire et secondaire">Primary and Secondary</option>
</select>

<div class="textIc">

    <p><?php  the_sub_field('left_section_heading'); ?></p>
    <p><?php  the_sub_field('left_section_subheading_1'); ?></p>
    <p><?php  the_sub_field('left_section_subheading_2'); ?></p>

</div>
```

Here is the jQuery code which is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#level').on('change', function () {
    var val = $(this).val()
    if (val == '00') {
      $(".textIc").show();
    } else {
      $("div p:not (:contains('val')").parent('textIc').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `$("div p:not (:contains("+val+")").parent('textIc').hide();` concat the var val

Comment: `parent('.textIc')` missing `.`

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. It is still showing all the content. No filtering is being done.

Comment: missing `.` ni parent()

Comment: $("div p:not (:contains("+val+")").parent('.textIc').hide();

Used this. Still if I select primary, it displays all the divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to do it like below:-

```
if ( val == '00'){
  $(".textIc").show();
}else{
  $('.textIc').each(function(){
    if($(this).children("p").text().indexOf(val) !==-1){
      $(this).show();
    }else{
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

***Demo Working example:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#level').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if ( val == '00'){
      $(".textIc").show();
    }else{
      $('.textIc').each(function(){
        if($(this).children("p").text().indexOf(val) !==-1){
          $(this).show();
        }else{
          $(this).hide();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="level">
  <option value="00" selected><b>Default</b></option>
  <option value="Primary">Primary</option>
  <option value="Secondary">Secondary</option>
  <option value="Primary and Secondary">Primary and Secondary</option>
</select>

<div class="textIc">

  <p>Primary</p>
  <p>King</p>
  <p>Queen</p>

</div>

<div class="textIc">

  <p>Secondary</p>
  <p>Secondary King</p>
  <p>Secondary Queen</p>

</div>
```

Working fiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/hbx2hqos/

Comment: @Jon_Snow  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution:- https://jsfiddle.net/xsugywzs/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#level').on('change', function () {
    var val = $(this).val()
    if (val == '00') {
      $("div p").show()
    } else {
      $("div p:contains("+val+")").show();
     $("div p:not(:contains("+val+"))").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="level">
  <option value="00" selected><b>Default</b></option>
  <option value="Primaire">Primary</option>
  <option value="Secondaire">Secondary</option>
  <option value="Primaire et secondaire">Primary and Secondary</option>
</select>

 <div class="textIc">
   <p>
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
      <b>Primaire</b>
     It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
   </p>
   <p>
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
     <b>Secondaire</b>
     It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 
   </p>
   <p>
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
     <b>Primaire et secondaire</b>
     It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. 
   </p>
   <p>
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
   </p>
 </div>
```

Comment: It works partially. Now it is only displaying the dropdown value and not the rest of the div. 
The div contains 3 lines and it is only displaying "primary". How can I set it to display the full div